# Is there are version of `setorder` that behaves like `setcolorder`

Tags: r, data.table

I want to reorder the rows of a `data.table` according to some given sequence of indices, which is what `setcolorder` does for columns. Is there a function for this?

Here is a reproducible example, with the expected output.

```
> DT = data.table(mtcars, keep.rownames=TRUE)[1:3]
> DT
              rn  mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1:     Mazda RX4 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2: Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
3:    Datsun 710 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1

> ord = c(3,1,2)
> setroworder(DT, ord)
> DT
              rn  mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1:    Datsun 710 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
2:     Mazda RX4 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
3: Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
```

Comment: Perhaps a non-reassigning version of `DT <- DT[vec,]`? (By "non-reassigning", I assume some form of internal assignment, not needing to reassign a table to itself like this.)

Comment: @r2evans I'm not sure how to do that. If you know, feel free to post an answer.

Comment: I don't see an issue (of the 698 current) that includes `order rows integer`, perhaps you can request/suggest a change? https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues

Comment: Imo, you should hold onto the column that captures the desired row order (assigned to NULL as a final step in both answers below) if doing multiple operations; and if doing only one operation, might as well do `DT[order(neworder), stuff_to_do]` without actually changing the row order.

Comment: @r2evens I opened an issue (#3686) requesting this feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> neworder should be the "lookup index" of the new ordering, e.g. neworder = c(3, 1, 2) gives the 3rd row as the new first row, the 1st row as the new second row, etc...

```
# example
DT = data.table(mtcars, keep.rownames=TRUE)[1:3]
ord = c(3,1,2)

DT

              rn  mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb 
1:     Mazda RX4 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4   
2: Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4   
3:    Datsun 710 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1   

# use DT[ord, do_stuff]:
setorderv(DT[ord, .rn := .I], ".rn")[]

              rn  mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb .rn
1:    Datsun 710 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1   1
2:     Mazda RX4 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4   2
3: Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4   3
```

As noted in a comment, I think it would be a bad idea to get rid of the column capturing the row ordering, but you can make a wrapper to get rid of it as in the other answers.

It may be necessary to use `1:.N` in a future version if the behavior of `.I` changes as discussed here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2598

Comment: Thanks for the link to the discussion, Frank. The prospect if using `.I`/`.i` (and `.N`/`.n`) as global/local seems intuitive-enough once you get used to `data.table`'s "arcane" (their word, not mine) fixed variables ... though likely too late for the `.N` change (for backward-compatibility). This clears up why so many of my `data.table` learning was broken when trying to use `.I`. Thanks!

Comment: This is the slickest answer. It looks like you achieved a non-reassigning version of `DT[ord,]` that @r2evans originally asked for. But I question the value of keeping `.rn`, which will always be `1:.N`.

Comment: @JamesHirschorn, I don't disagree with Frank's suggestion to *not discard* the variable ... but at the same time, it seems it might be "cluttering my data". If it's a one-time ordering and/or ordering will otherwise never change (i.e., no joins, additions, deletions), perhaps deleting it has no effect. I agree, this is the simplest of the answers (so far).

Comment: @JamesHirschorn Yeah, I guess I don't trust myself not to reorder tables later on (eg, rbind multiple of them or another setkey) and I like transparency (so I and anyone else can see "hey, this table is keyed, so think twice before messing with the order") and the option to reorder and then revert. I guess if the table is very large, I might drop the column to save RAM and horizontal space when printing the table; or if I was very near the end of my code (eg, about to print the result to R markdown).

Comment: @JamesH Thanks for the edit. Re your post on github, you might want to edit it to be a clear FR rather than requiring folks to click through (when they might be reading email notifications) and to then parse out what part of our StackOverflow Q&A is the FR. Some post guidelines/expectations for data.table are here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Support

Comment: @Frank I did have "Feature request" in the title, but a developer changed this to a feature request label (I didn't know about adding labels). He also said my SO question was "badly asked", so I have edited my question to give a reproducible example with the expected output.

Comment: @JamesHirschorn Thanks. Yeah, only project owners on github can add tags like "feature request" so nothing more you could have done with that. Generally, I think it is better to post complete issue descriptions on that site, since questions and feature requests naturally have different formatting; people read the github issues in email often; etc.

Answer (score 3):

If your integer vector is not inherent to the table, then I don't see a function to do it automatically (I hope others will chime in, I'm not a `data.table`-guru). Lacking that, here's a quick function, with annoying `message` calls to show the object memory address, to show this is done internally (and not changing the memory location):

```r
setroworder <- function(DT, vec, verbose = TRUE, vecname = NA) {
  if (is.logical(verbose)) verbose <- if (verbose) message else c
  verbose("# ", data.table::address(DT))
  if (is.na(vecname)) {
    # find an unused name
    vecname <- make.unique(c(colnames(DT), "vec"))[ ncol(DT) + 1L ]
  }
  verbose("# ", data.table::address(DT))
  set(DT, i = NULL, j = vecname, value = order(vec))
  verbose("# ", data.table::address(DT))
  setorderv(DT, vecname)
  verbose("# ", data.table::address(DT))
  set(DT, j = vecname, value = NULL)
  verbose("# ", data.table::address(DT))
  invisible(DT) # convenience only, this function operates in side-effect
}
```

In action:

```r
x <- data.table(a = 1:10)
setroworder(x, c(3,1,2,4:10))[]
# # 0000000012EFF1A8
# # 0000000012EFF1A8
# # 0000000012EFF1A8
# # 0000000012EFF1A8
# # 0000000012EFF1A8
#      a
#  1:  3
#  2:  1
#  3:  2
#  4:  4
#  5:  5
#  6:  6
#  7:  7
#  8:  8
#  9:  9
# 10: 10
```

Comment: Actually, this answer (as well as my original answer) are wrong in that they do not give the same behaviour as `setcolorder` (see my edit).

Comment: Interesting point. Though I was not familiar with `sort.int(..., index.return=TRUE)`, I think `order` suffices as well.

Comment: Right, I see you edited your solution so that it now gives the "correct" behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**. The original answer did not give behaviour equivalent to `secolorder`. `neworder` should be the "lookup index" of the new ordering, e.g. `neworder = c(3, 1, 2)` gives the 3rd row as the new first row, the 1st row as the new second row, etc...

Here is my solution:

```
setroworder <- function(x, neworder) {
  # This is assumes that there is some convention that colnames do not start with '.'.
  # I don't know if there is any such convention though.
  x[, .indexcol := sort.int(neworder, index.return = TRUE)$ix]
  setorder(x, .indexcol)
  x[, .indexcol := NULL]
}
```

Testing it out:

```
> x <- as.data.table(mtcars)
> head(x)
    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
3: 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
4: 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
5: 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
6: 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
> set.seed(42)
> head(setroworder(x, sample(32)))
    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1: 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
2: 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
3: 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
4: 19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
5: 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
6: 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
```

Comment: Looks like you found a working answer, the only differences being: dynamic variable name, and optional verbosity. Good job. (I had to delete temporarily hunting down a non-reproducibility issue caused by me poisoning my `mtcars` source.)